# how to use pageddatasource with datatable and without sql statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm not using the any `sql` table but i want to insert the pageddatasource with datatable. If it is possible or not.

this is my code

```
Private Sub GenerateDownloadLinks()
    Dim path__1 As String = Server.MapPath("..\Fileupload\insert\")
    If Directory.Exists(path__1) Then
        Dim ShowContent As New DataTable()
        ShowContent.Columns.Add("Image", GetType(String))
        ShowContent.Columns.Add("DownloadLink", GetType(String))
        ShowContent.Columns.Add("FileName", GetType(String))
        Dim di As New DirectoryInfo(path__1)
        For Each fi As FileInfo In di.GetFiles()
            Dim dr As DataRow = ShowContent.NewRow()
            dr("FileName") = fi.Name
            dr("DownloadLink") = Server.MapPath("..\Fileupload\insert\") + fi.Name
            Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(fi.FullName)
            Select Case ext
                Case ".rtf"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\word.png")
                    Exit Select
                Case ".np"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\notepad.png")
                    Exit Select
                Case ".txt"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\text.png")
                    Exit Select
                Case ".jpg"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\image.png")
                    Exit Select
                Case ".png"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\img.png")
                    Exit Select
                Case ".gif"
                    dr("Image") = ResolveUrl("..\Fileupload\images\mp.png")
                    Exit Select
            End Select
            ShowContent.Rows.Add(dr)
        Next
        Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
        ds.Tables.Add("ShowContent")
        Dim pds As New PagedDataSource()
        pds.DataSource = ShowContent
        pds.AllowPaging = True
        pds.PageSize = 9
        totalpage = Math.Round(pds.DataSourceCount / 9)
        pds.CurrentPageIndex = currentpageindex
        datalist.DataSource = pds
        datalist.DataMember = "ShowContent"
        datalist.DataBind()
    End If
 End Sub
```

I got a error is:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
```

Thanks,

Comment: in which line the error is pointing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your data source for the `PagedDataSource` from `DataTable` to `DataSet`. Because `Datasource` property is expecting the `IEnumerable` object.

```
  pds.DataSource = ds.defaultview ;
```

Comment: I solve this Problem.  This Solution is pds.datasource=ds.defaultview;